# Synchronized Vs Semaphore

Tags: java, semaphore, monitor, synchronized

While reading concurrency in Java, I have following doubts:

1. Does Java provides lower level construct then synchronized for synchronization?
2. In what circumstances will we use semaphore over synchronized (which provides monitor behaviour in Java)

Comment: i think for question 1 , we can use ReentrantLock and Condition objects ,, they are kind of lower level constructs..

Answer (score 57):

Synchronized allows only **one** thread of execution to access the resource at the same time. Semaphore allows up to **n** (you get to choose n) threads of execution to access the resource at the same time.

Answer (score 12):

1. There is also `volatile` keyword, according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html `volatile` variable access is more efficient than accessing these variables through synchronized code
2. `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` is used to restrict the number of threads that can access a resource. That is, while `synchronized` allows only one thread to aquire lock and execute the synchonized block / method, Semaphore gives permission up to n threads to go and blocks the others.

Comment: synchronized provides solution to both Thread interference and memory consistency errors , however volatile only provides solution to memory consistency errors,, so we cannot use volatile to provide atomicity in operations,, am I missing something here ?

Comment: volatile provides also atomic access to long / double

Comment: With volatile you may still have dirty reads and corrupt your shared values. So it is not a alternative for synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

There is also [atomics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html).  This gives access to the basic hardware compare-and-swap command that's the basis of all synchronization.  It allows you, for example, to increment a number safely.  If you `++` a volatile field, another thread executing the same instruction could read the field before your thread writes to it, then write back to it *after* your thread.  So one increment gets lost.  Atomics do the read and write "atomically" and so avoid the problem.

Actually, volatiles, synchronized statements, *and* atomics tend to force all thread data to be refreshed from main memory and/or written to main memory as appropriate, so none of them are *really* that low level.  (I'm simplifying here.  Unlike C#, Java does not really have a concept of "main memory".)