# How a Critical Section tagged by synchronized keyword is different from using a Semaphore?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Lets say I have critical section code written in method A

```
public void A(){
  //Critical Section 
}
```

I can make it synchronized so as to allow exclusive access to it

```
synchronized public void A(){ }
```

Or alternatively I can also use a `Semaphore` class in java

How these two approaches differ in working ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronized Vs Semaphore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907992/synchronized-vs-semaphore)

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Answer (score 1):

When using semaphore, you have to remeber to acquire it before critical section and release it after, but you can give access for more threads. Therefore it is **commonly used to limit access to resources** such as connection pools. You can also gain access to Semaphore object and all it's methods such as `tryAcquire` which lets you write more flexible code - nevertheless in case of critical sections it is better to use `Lock` class (just due to it's purpose) - if not `synchronized` block.

`synchronized` block is simple "lower level" (than Semaphores) synchronization, it just gives access to section for one thread. You can also limit synchronized block to code which is indeed critical section by using construction:

```
synchronized(? extends Object) {
    // critical section
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have gathered a list of interesting links that will shed some light on the differences.

First, be aware that the nomenclature concerning locks/synchronized/monitors is *messed up* and people (sometimes) use these terms interchangeably.

Second, the links below are *not* ordered by importance/relevance/clarity

- http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynchP.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html
- [What's the meaning of an object's monitor in Java? Why use this word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848616/whats-the-meaning-for-objects-monitor-in-java-why-use-this-word)
- https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Synchronization
- http://www.takipiblog.com/2013/08/15/5-things-you-didnt-know-about-synchronization-in-java-and-scala/
- [Semaphore vs. Monitors - what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335950/semaphore-vs-monitors-whats-the-difference)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)
- http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/operating-systems/monitors-vs-semaphores/